# matplotlib: histogram is not displaying

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to draw histogram but nothing appears in the Figure Window.
My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [1000000, 1525097, 2050194, 1095638, 1620736, 2145833, 1191277, 1716375, 1286916, 1382555]

plt.hist(values, 10, histtype = 'bar', facecolor = 'blue')
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.xlabel("Bin Number")
plt.title("Histogram")
plt.axis([0,11,0,220000])
plt.show()
```

This is the output:
[image]

I am trying to achieve this plot
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: `plt.axis([0,11,0,220000])` this makes no sense. Can you say a word or two about why you included this and what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was wrong, my bad... I added it at start when my plot was displaying negative values... don't know why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing what a histogram is. The histogram that can be produced with the given data is as given below.

A histogram basically counts how many given values fall within a given range.

You have given incorrect arguments to the axis() function. The ending value is `2200000` You missed a single zero. Also you have swapped the arguments. Limits of the x axis comes first and then the limits of the Y axis. This is the modified code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [1000000, 1525097, 2050194, 1095638, 1620736, 2145833, 1191277, 1716375, 1286916, 1382555]

plt.hist(values, 10, histtype = 'bar', facecolor = 'blue')
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.xlabel("Bin Number")
plt.title("Histogram")
plt.axis([0,2200000,0,11])
plt.show()
```

This is the histogram generated:

[image]

Comment: Yes that is my mistake but even changing 220000 with 2200000 didn't fix anything, I am trying to put 0-10 along x-axis and 0-2200000 along y-axis. Thanks anyway

Comment: @SohailAshraf You misunderstand what a histogram is. See the updated answer.

Comment: No I didn't misunderstand. Please check the output I want to generate in question above... Thanks

Comment: @SohailAshraf It is not possible to generate such an output from the given histogram. Atleast that is not what a histogram does. You will have to generate 1000000 values of '1' , and so on and then plot the histogram

Comment: Sorry, I get it... I was doing it wrong way, It is not possible... I need to use the bar chart. Anyway thanks for your help...

Comment: @SohailAshraf  No probs :D . Please mark the answer as accepted if this helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I finally achieved it...

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [1000000, 1525097, 2050194, 1095638, 1620736, 2145833, 1191277, 1716375, 1286916, 1382555]
strategy = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
value = np.array(values)
strategies = np.array(strategy)
plt.bar(strategy, values, .8)
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.xlabel("Bin Number")
plt.title("Histogram")
plt.axis([1,11,0,2200000])
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]